# How to disable Reachability swipe down when UIDatePicker show up

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have UIDatePicker with picker style .wheels
It is annoying when users try to scroll the wheels and the app keeps swiping down.
Is there any way to disable the Reachability swipe down when DatePicker shows up?[image]
[image]